# Simplest way to connect a Visual Studio SharePoint App to my external Database

Tags: visual-studio, database, linq

Hi all new to developing for SharePoint.

As the title indicates I want to connect my Visual Studio SharePoint App that I have created to my external database. I have created the app and it works in SharePoint. Now I want to connect that same app to my Database. I was thinking of using Linq to SQL and reading the connection string from the app.config file, but I could not seem to get that to work, maybe I can't do it that way.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint online or on premise?

Comment: This would be for SharePoint on premise.

Comment: Have you tried creating an External Content Type and then using External Lists?

Comment: Why didn't it work?